# Can installer have a different icon than the launcher, in install4j?

Tags: install4j

Our clients do click on installer (which they save it on Desktop) instead of launcher thus running installer instead of the the actual program.

Is there a way to specify an icon for installer and a different icon for launcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two icons are never shared. The icon for a generated launcher is defined on the "Icon"  step of the launcher wizard, the installer icon is defined if you go to Installer->Screens & Actions, select the installer and edit its "Executable icon" property.